# restriction on the number of tables in hbase and its impact on performance

Tags: hbase

Our hbase schema in production has 5 tables. We have N clients where in only 10% of the clients are active at any given instant. So for me it looks like a waste of resources to keep the data of remaining 90% clients active. I was thinking of creating 5 tables per client so that I can keep the active client's tables enabled and the remaining client's tables disabled. From what I have read if we exceed 1000 regions per region server then performance starts degrading. But I am sure not to hit that limit. My questions

1. If I disable a set of tables then does it mean that I am putting less load on hbase?
2. Does this seem like a sound strategy overall?

Answer (score 0):

What are your expectations about performances ?

How would you determine which clients are active/inacyive ?

How would you disable automatically unused tables for inactive clients ?

What is then the access pattern for reads ? Will your clients read data only in its single table ?

Handling lots of tables results in several issues :

- more regions, as 1 table consists in -at least- 1 region, even if there are no data. HBase will have to handle more active StoreFiles, etc.
- more memstore (ie: memory use) because there are not flushed to disk (HFile) regularly but only if they reach the configured threshold.

Comment: by clients I mean customers. I would have prior knowledge of which customers are going to access my app and when they are going to access it. This would help me in disabling tables either through java or in a simplistic case I can do it manually. The access pattern for reads is that clients would be served data from their respective 5 tables. Does disabling a table reduce the resource requirement (like heap, etc.) of hbase?

Comment: I guess the two issues that you mention would arise only if I am keeping those tables active. If I know that a set of tables is not going to be accessed in the next two months then can I disable those tables and save some resources?